# Insert excel file data into SQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, excel

After the extraction of data, it saves to an excel file. I would like it to save in MySQL database instead of the excel file.

Platform used: Eclipse, MySQL

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Does it map to the database?

Comment: First of all - read docs about it. If you wait that we'll do all your job - you are wrong. Ask the question. Don't make us to solve your problems

Answer (score 1):

To implement this , you need to have 2 JAR FILES that are APACHE-POI and [mysql-connector.](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/jars/jarClasses/34437)

First, to fetch data from excel file , you need to use [APACHE-POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library.
And as you get data row by row , insert data into mysql table using mysql-connector jar file.

It will be easy if the Structure of the excel file is same as table in MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality By using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) and [mysql connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

you can also check [JexcelAPI](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and [JXL](http://jxl.sourceforge.net/).

as @vicky said maintaining the structure of your excel same as database table will make your 
job easy and that way you will get less errors comparatively.

Comment: @Androidf u may select one of the posts as answer